# Site Collection Administrator has left the building

Tags: 2007, site-collection, central-administration

We have an issue with some of our SharePoint MOS (2007) installs - the SCA has left the organisation and taken his privileges with him, and we need to reassign his role to someone else.

Is there any way to do this without deleting the whole shebang and redoing everything?

I am no SharePoint expert at any level, but this is something that we're going to have to recover.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok Paul, you will need help from Share-point admins (someone with server access to the Sharepoint farm). You need someone with SharePoint admin privilege to open Central Administration and update the Primary\Secondary site administrator. I don't have any 2007 running so steps here are from sp2013 but it is very similar.

1. Open Central admin
2. Open application management.
3. Click on Change site collection administrators.
4. Choose correct web app and site collection, change the admins and click ok.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Marek, that sounds pretty useful. I actually have server admin on this server, so I could grant myself the rights and take it from there.

Comment: It depends how central admin has been configured. You need to be member of the Farm admin group. Normally the built in administrators group is member of the farm admin so by adding yourself to that group on the server that hosts central admin (usually it is only one of the servers in the farm)

Comment: Marek, thank-you for your help - this cracked the issue.  I've replaced the original administrators, so we can manage the application properly from this point forward.

Comment: you are welcome, as a side note I would point to an upgrade. SP2007 is out of life support and going forward you may encounter issues with it not being compatible with newer browsers. SP07 worked best with IE now with MS switching browsing engine to chromium your users may face issues. And growing security risk is as well an factor.

Comment: Yes - we know.  We were going to aim for 2010, but that's out of service shortly too. The main issue for us is that the MOSS services are free...  Public organisation and so on; money's tight!  Thanks again, Marek.

Comment: Just to add to your post, Marek, I discovered that, if you're in the Administrator's group on the SharePoint server, this is sufficient to get you into Central Admin.  I'm not sure if this is dependant on the age of the server, however (this one is Server 2003 - yes, I know!  Don't ask!)

Comment: no this is not dependedant on the age of the server ;). By default the BuildIN\Administrators is added to the farm administrators group (you can check it via Central Admin --> Security --> Farm admins

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any experience on SP2007 but stsadm may help you I guess. You can set another user as a site collection administrator. [This link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5afd18f5-f825-4e5e-b755-519867cf2765/stsadm-command-to-add-site-collection-admins?forum=sharepointadminlegacy) and [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-2007-products-and-technologies/cc262637(v=office.12)) may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, newbie - I'll take a look at those links.

Comment: I lol'd at this comment.